# Bootstrap: Maintain table size fixed horizontally during collapse/expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a really long text in one of the column of my table. So I am using bootstrap provided collapse/expand button to hide/show that long text (cell data).

But when I click on the button to collapse/expand the text, the table flickers and gets resized horizontally.

How do I prevent the table columns from re-sizing horizontally during collapse/expand of that table data ? And allow the expansion of text ONLY vertically limited within that column width ?

Below is the HTML for reference.

```
<table id="query_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

    <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>Description</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>


    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>ORDER_ZONE</td>
        <td>2018-06-18 21:47:31.0</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseExample_9" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseExample_9">
                Show/hide Description
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample_9">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    SOME VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT HERE
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>ORDER_ZONE</td>
        <td>2018-06-18 21:47:31.0</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseExample_10" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseExample_10">
                Show/hide Description
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample_10">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    ANOTHER VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT HERE
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***table-layout: fixed*** css for your table and you might have to give some fixed width for table itself and/or its cells.